# Ubercart keeps items in the cart for different sessions

Tags: session, drupal, drupal-6, session-cookies, ubercart

I started off adding items to a cart using a non-logged in user. Added a product to the cart and then I realized I already have an account. I just fill up my details and gets logged in. What I see in the cart is now the item still remains in the cart what I have added when I was performing checkout as an anonymous user.

The sessions for anonymous user and authenticated user should be different and hence the items.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is working as intended. As anon, you can start shopping and your cart won't get lost when you login or register. That said, you can create a rule to empty the cart on login; which in my opinion is a bad user experience.

Comment: This case is good if you initially comes to the site and add items to cart and then login with your account so that you don't have to add items again in your cart. But I am talking about the case if a anon user just add items to the cart and then leave it there and suddenly other registered user visits the site with the same IP address. In that case he shouldn't be able to see any items in cart.

Comment: Cart is not saved based on IP. This can only happen if the anon user leaves the browser open. What you described shouldn't happen. Do you use any custom/contrib module to alter the cart behaviour?

Comment: My problem is that the anonymous user cart and registered cart should be different. When I add items to the cart as an anonymous user and why this item is shown in the cart when I am logged in with the account.

Comment: @samirchauhan even though this might be resurrecting a dead thread... there isn't a single "anonymous user cart". You had a session with the site in your browser on your computer that wasn't associated with a user login. When that browser on that computer while the session is still valid logs in Ubercart *correctly* figures out its your basket. It isn't the case that if someone else had logged in on a different computer that they would have seen the basket